# Pierde el sincronismo al aumentar el intervalo de tiempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema, al aumentar el tiempo de ***setInterval***.

Explico de que se trata, tengo dos texto una del lado derecho y el otro del lado izquierdo. En el de el lado derecho tengo una palabra la cual busco en un grupo de palabras que tengo en el lado izquierdo y la cambio de color. Lo que me esta sucediendo que a un intervalo de ***1000 ms***, me trabaja sin problema pero cuando lo reduzco a ***500ms*** ya no me realiza el efecto del cambio de color de la palabra en el texto del lado izquierdo. Les dejo el código de javascript para ver si me pueden ayudar.

```js
var xa = "primario|comida, nopal, tahúr, cartílago, foto, expulsión, primario, siglo, yerba, grasa, tesis, minuto~zacate|vegetal, zacate, sabor, veneno, horario, sexual, anacoreta, aceptar, inventar, zacate, protesta, arrojar~rito|frustración, rito, ensalzar, filósofo, léxico, rito, avalar, luz, esquimal, rito, ministro~cabra|tauro, palo, cabra, indigno, bienvenida, sopa, insípido, hablar, causa, farol, armazón, consejo~urbe|anfitrión, rival, domar, olivo, mano, urbe, desenfoque, acento, pastel, maduro, cordones, urbe~milenio|milenio, mejor, hortaliza, norteño, jade, milenio, pequeño, garbo, plata, naturales, milenio, yogur~hostal|invierno, hostal, mamut, sonrisa, niño, futbolista, noria, divisiones, servicio, consomé, bigotes, hundir";
var tipo = '';
var interval = '';
var npal = 0;
var tpal = '';
get_palmin(60, set_buspal);

function set_buspal(){
   var a = xa.split("~");
  len = a.length;
  tprt = tpal - 1000;
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * len) + 1);
  $("#text1").addClass('txt-mitad2');
  $("#text2").addClass('txt-mitad2');
  //Separamos las parte del segundo array.
  if((npal + 1) == len){
   $("#text1").show('fast',function(){
    a2 = a[npal].split("|");
    $(this).html(a2[0]);
    $("#text2").html("");
    setTimeout(function(){
      wd = a2[1];
      $("#text2").html(wd);
      setTimeout(function(){
       if(tipo == 21){
        var search = a2[2].trim();      
       }else{
        var search = a2[0].trim();      
       }
       $("#text2:contains('"+search+"')").each(function () {
              var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
              $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, '<span style="color: #00ff00">'+search+'</span>'));
          });
         npal = 0;               
      },tprt);
    },tprt);    
   });
  }else{
   $("#text1").show('fast',function(){
    a2 = a[npal].split("|");
    $(this).html(a2[0]);
    $("#text2").html("");
    setTimeout(function(){
      wd = a2[1];
      $("#text2").html(wd);
      setTimeout(function(){
       if(tipo == 21){
        var search = a2[2].trim();      
       }else{
        var search = a2[0].trim();      
       }
       $("#text2:contains('"+search+"')").each(function () {
              var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
              $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, '<span style="color: #00ff00">'+search+'</span>'));
          });
         npal++;               
      },tprt);
    },tprt);    
   });
  }
 }
  
function get_palmin(val = '', fn = '', wd = true) {
  if (wd != '' && (tipo == 19 || tipo == 21)) {
    if (wd) {
      n_wd = 10;
    } else {
      n_wd = wd.split(" ").length;
    }
    pal = (60 / val) * n_wd;
    tpal = pal * 1000;
  } else {
    pal = 60 / val;
    tpal = pal * 1000;
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(fn, tpal);
}

$("#rango").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  get_palmin(val, set_buspal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row show-grid" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="span2" id="text1" style="color: #0000ff; height:40px; " align="right"></div>
  <div class="span7" id="text2" align="left"></div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div><input type="range" name="rango" class="input-xxlarge" id="rango" step="1" min="1" max="2000" value="60"></div>
</div>
```

> Nota: el valor esta fijado a 60 palabras por minuto y en la función
>   **get_palmin** es donde se fija el valor del ***setInterval***

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código HTML disculpa? Para poder hacer pruebas en JSFiddle por favor

Comment: Ya coloque el texto html, el contenido del div es dinámico pues colocar cualquiera.  Del lado derecho una palabra y del izquierdo un grupo,  si tiene que estar contenido aunque sea una vez la palabra.

Comment: no esta definido `xa` , `setinterval` no lo utilizar, realmente no se como ayudarte

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta coloque todos los valores que intervienen agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: también sugiero una prueba con JSFiddle, porque no comprendo completamente el problema.

Comment: Acabo de colocar el ejemplo funcionando para ver si me puede ayudar gracias a todos de antemano

Comment: Creo que el problema es que entre el ratio de refresco del monitor y los reflejos del cerebro humano a una mayor velocidad el efecto no se logra apreciar.

pero no es un problema de código, cuando lo pones a la máxima velocidad puedes ver palabras coloreadas.

Comment: Hola todos lo que me ayudaron ya edite mi respuesta con la solución que encontré gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Mejor publica la solución y márcala como correcta.

Comment: Ok en seguida lo hago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí les dejo la solución que encontré. Espero que le sea de utilidad a alguien mas.
Básicamente lo que hice, fue calcular un % de del tiempo que refrescaba la función ***set_buspal()*** y se valor fijarlo en el método ***setTimeout*** ya de esta manera no me refresca la función antes de que yo cambie de color las palabras.
Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

```js
var xa = "primario|comida, nopal, tahúr, cartílago, foto, expulsión, primario, siglo, yerba, grasa, tesis, minuto~zacate|vegetal, zacate, sabor, veneno, horario, sexual, anacoreta, aceptar, inventar, zacate, protesta, arrojar~rito|frustración, rito, ensalzar, filósofo, léxico, rito, avalar, luz, esquimal, rito, ministro~cabra|tauro, palo, cabra, indigno, bienvenida, sopa, insípido, hablar, causa, farol, armazón, consejo~urbe|anfitrión, rival, domar, olivo, mano, urbe, desenfoque, acento, pastel, maduro, cordones, urbe~milenio|milenio, mejor, hortaliza, norteño, jade, milenio, pequeño, garbo, plata, naturales, milenio, yogur~hostal|invierno, hostal, mamut, sonrisa, niño, futbolista, noria, divisiones, servicio, consomé, bigotes, hundir";
var tipo = '';
var interval = '';
var npal = 0;
var tpal = '';
get_palmin(60, set_buspal);

 function set_buspal(){
   var a = xa.split("~");
  len = a.length;
  tprt = (tpal * 8) / 100;
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * len) + 1);
  $("#text1").addClass('txt-mitad2');
  $("#text2").addClass('txt-mitad2');
  //Separamos las parte del segundo array.
  if((npal + 1) == len){
   $("#text1").show('fast',function(){
    a2 = a[npal].split("|");
    $(this).html(a2[0]);
    $("#text2").html("");
    setTimeout(function(){
      wd = a2[1];
      $("#text2").html(wd);
      setTimeout(function(){
       if(tipo == 21){
        var search = a2[2].trim();      
       }else{
        var search = a2[0].trim();      
       }
       $("#text2:contains('"+search+"')").each(function () {
              var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
              $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, '<span style="color: #00ff00">'+search+'</span>'));
          });
         npal = 0;               
      },tprt);
    },tprt);    
   });
  }else{
   $("#text1").show('fast',function(){
    a2 = a[npal].split("|");
    $(this).html(a2[0]);
    $("#text2").html("");
    setTimeout(function(){
      wd = a2[1];
      $("#text2").html(wd);
      setTimeout(function(){
       if(tipo == 21){
        var search = a2[2].trim();      
       }else{
        var search = a2[0].trim();      
       }
       $("#text2:contains('"+search+"')").each(function () {
              var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
              $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, '<span style="color: #00ff00">'+search+'</span>'));
          });
         npal++;               
      },tprt);
    },tprt);    
   });
  }
 }
  
function get_palmin(val = '', fn = '', wd = true) {
  if (wd != '' && (tipo == 19 || tipo == 21)) {
    if (wd) {
      n_wd = 10;
    } else {
      n_wd = wd.split(" ").length;
    }
    pal = (60 / val) * n_wd;
    tpal = pal * 1000;
  } else {
    pal = 60 / val;
    tpal = pal * 1000;
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(fn, tpal);
}

$("#rango").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  get_palmin(val, set_buspal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row show-grid" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="span2" id="text1" style="color: #0000ff; height:40px; " align="right"></div>
  <div class="span7" id="text2" align="left"></div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div><input type="range" name="rango" class="input-xxlarge" id="rango" step="1" min="1" max="2000" value="60"></div>
</div>
```